# dry-run `svn add` on a directory

Tags: git, svn

In `git` I can use:

```
git add . -A -n
```

to execute a dry-run `add` and see which files will get added. Is there a way to do something similar in `svn` so that I can examine safely which files will get added recursively when I add a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of. You don't really need it though, as long as you don't commit the files your repo will be unchanged. I'd do the add and look at the file status via `svn status` and adjust that list to match your needs. Once you have it nailed down, do an `svn commit`.

Comment: ... and keep using `snv revert --recursive folder-name` till I get it right I suppose?

Comment: To remove a whole folder tree, sure. Otherwise just `svn rm` individual files as needed.